# Cannot install a downloaded flashplayer 11 application for linux

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded flashplayer 11 for linux, but do not know how to install it on my ubuntu 14.04. Flashplayer is from the ADOBE website.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to download anything. You can run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

and flash will be installed.

Ubuntu is not Windows. In most of cases you do not need to download software from sites.

Comment: Hmm, not 99.9%? ;)

Comment: @A.B. I doubt that too ;-) But it depends on the user. For most of people it is 100%. But I will soften it a bit.